# Allow newer SQL syntax to fallback gracefully on older versions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm supporting an ageing ASP.net system that has to run on numerous customers' older installations of SQL Server (back to 2005).

Is there any way to use features of later versions of SQL Server without running into `Incorrect syntax near....` errors?

The current feature I'd like to use is `AT DATE TIME` on Azure SQL 12 e.g. `select CONVERT(datetime, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time')` to implement a custom `GETDATE()` function, but earlier Sql versions refuse to compile it.

Is the only option running `exec()` on a sql string, or is there a more graceful solution?

```
--do a version check, and then run the appropriate sql string?
if (CHARINDEX('Azure', @@VERSION,0) > 0)    
    exec('select CONVERT(datetime, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE ''GMT Standard Time'')')
else
    select getDate()
```

Comment: You can't execute new statements on an old database. The engine in 2005 doesn't understand that statement.

Comment: Hmmm. As I wrote this, running exec() on a sql string started to seem like a pretty reasonable solution to this, but any ideas about other approaches would appreciated.

Comment: @SeanLange is there no accepted way to work around this? Like an `#if` directive in c#? (I realize this is probably grasping at straws!)

Comment: You can only go forward with compatibility mode that i am aware.

Comment: #if is a compiler directive and there is no such thing in t-sql. And logically it isn't the same thing here. You are basically saying can I run a .net 4.5 statement in .net 3.0. It is a different engine and the old one doesn't know anything about the new one.

Comment: One way could be by creating your own procedure / function for getting the time, and then installing different version based on what the database version is.

Comment: 1) dynamic sql, which is what you are doing.  2) have the client check the version fist, then adjust its queries/requests (which is really just pushing the dynamic part to the client). 3) use stored procedures written specifically for the version of SQL Server they reside in.  #3 is the preferred solution.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks, that seems like a pretty good summation of the possibilities as I understand the situation, if you want to write it up as an answer I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are as follows:

1. Dynamic Sql, which is what you are doing.
2. Have the client program/app check the version first, then adjust its queries/requests (which is really just pushing the dynamic part to the client).
3. Use stored procedures written specifically for the version of SQL Server they reside in.

Of these, #3 is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for work around for your code...

```
DECLARE @LocalOffset INT = -5
DECLARE @DaylightSavings INT = 0
DECLARE @OffSet INT = @LocalOffset + @DaylightSavings
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,@OffSet,GETUTCDATE())
```

There are obviously other ways to achieve your goal. I'd just populate a Table or View with all the time zones and then handle your DST according to if that time zone even does it.